# multiple serialise call in rxjx on server side using Request module

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I have to make multiple serialise call on server side in **NodeJs** using  [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) , and **RxJs Observable**

I have array of Url Address like ['www.google.com','facebook.com']
When I make request to call then server get busy in event loop . I want to know when my last url call gets response so that I can send response to front end
here is my code so far

```
 const foo = Observable.create(function (observer) {
         res.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
         var str = '<html><head></head><body><h1> Following are the responses: </h1><ul>'
         res.write(str);
         let count = 0;
         addressesArray.forEach(function (element, i) {

         observer.next(element);
         if (some Condition) {
            console.log('here i want to call complete when I get last response')     
       // observer.complete();   
         }


         })
     })
```

and this is my subscribe function

```
     const subscription = foo.subscribe({
         next : addres =>
         {
             request(addres , function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

                     console.log(response)


                 }
                if (typeof response === "undefined" || typeof body === "undefined") {
                     console.log('No resp')
                 }
            })

     },
     complete:()=>{console.log('done')}


 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start off your Observable from `addressesArray` with `from` operator, it'll complete itself when it reach the end of the array

```
from(addressesArray).pipe(
    mergeMap(address => {
        return new Observable(obs => {
            request(address, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
                    obs.next(response)
                else
                    obs.next('')
                obs.complete()
            })
        })
    }),
    reduce((allResponses, response) => {
        return allResponse += '<li>' + response + '<li/>'
    }, ''),
    tap(allResponses => {
        res.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
        var str = '<html><head></head><body><h1> Following are the responses: </h1><ul>'
        res.write(allResponses + '</ul')
        res.end()
    })
).subscribe()
```

Comment: should I call next in map function ? @Fan

Comment: what about subscribe function ?

Comment: There's no next for you to call. from() is turning your array into a stream of emission. You do need to subscribe to make it run

Comment: I have to check the response for each call where I can do that @Fan ?

Comment: how i can subscribe this function ? there is no request code

Comment: thank you for ur great time and help, works perfectly @Fan :) recommend me some docs for this too  . Thanks again :)

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io is a very good resource with samples for you to play with different operator